# Novice C++, seeking help in array division

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

#include <valarray>

using namespace std;

// to get new card number
int main ()
{

    int i;
    int array[5]= {10,2,6,34,51};
    valarray<int> v[5];


    int v %= 13;
    for (int i=0; i<5 ; i++) {

        cout << v[i]%=13 << " ";
    }


    }
```

hello, my goal is to get the array to perform a modulus division by number 13.

I've search and try a few different way but I can't figure out a way to make it work.....

Thank you...

Comment: You should be getting a compiler error from the code you show, where you *redefine* the variable `v` and also use an illegal initialization operator for it. That in turn might lead to more errors in the loop. Also, you don't declare one `valarray<int>` object with five elements, you declare an array of five `valarray<int>` object, each containing zero elements. Lastly, aren't you supposed to use `array` instead? And only the modulo operator `%` and not the modulo-assign operator?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the problems with your code:

- `valarray` does not have the same notation as normal arrays: `valarray<int> v[5];` declares 5 different `valarray` objects and puts them in a C-style array. The notation you are looking for is `valarray<int> v(10);`
- Get rid of the `int v %= 13;` line: this redefines v (an array) as an integer.
- Use `v[i]=(array[i]%13);` for the calculation, what you have doesn't make sense.
- Then output `cout << v[i] << " "`;

Also, you aren't really using any of the features of `valarray`, so it may make more sense just to use one single array, like:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// to get new card number
int main ()
{
    int array[5]= {10,2,6,34,51};
    for (int i=0; i<5 ; i++) {
        array[i]%=13;
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Edit: by the way, the cool thing about `valarray` here is that you can apply the same function to every value at once. Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    valarray<int> v(10);
    for (int i=0;i<10;++i) {
        v[i]=i*i; //Fill the array with 0,1,4,9,16,... as an example
    }
    v%=13; //This applies the modulo 13 on the whole array at once.
    for (int i=0;i<10;++i) {
        cout << v[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow. That was so much easier than I thought.  Holy crap.... Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want something like...

```
int array[5]= {10,2,6,34,51};
int v[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    v[i] = array[i] % 13;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    std::cout << v[i] << " ";
std::cout << '\n';
```